How do I combine MimeTypeFilters and NameFilters for a QFileDialog using PyQt6 or PyQt5?
Using PyQt6, I am investigating using QFileDialog directly without the use of one of the static functions (i.e. don't use QFileDialog.getOpenFileName). The issue that I am running into is creating a filter list that uses a combination of MIME types and named types.
For example, say you want to set a filter for *.css and *.qss files. At there core, they are essentially the same file type, however MIME doesn't recognize *.qss. I really like the idea of using MIME types because it ensures that the many extension options of a file type are included (i.e. [*.jpg, *.jpeg, *.jpe] or [*.md, *.mkd, *.markdown]), but I also need to work with the files that are not included in MIME.
The code snippet that I am working with is as follows:
file_dialog = QFileDialog()
file_dialog.setFileMode(QFileDialog.FileMode.ExistingFiles)
file_dialog.setMimeTypeFilters(["text/css",
                                "application/octet-stream"])
file_dialog.setNameFilter("Qt Style Sheet (*.qss)")

if file_dialog.exec():
    print(file_dialog.selectedFiles())

When this code executes, the .setNameFilter function completely overwrites the filters set with the .setMimeTypeFilters function. If I reverse the order of the filter setting, the same thing happens just in reverse.
I have also tried adding the name filter to the MIME type list, but the name filter is just ignored.
file_dialog.setMimeTypeFilters(["text/css",
                                "Qt Style Sheet (*.qss)",
                                "application/octet-stream"])

Anyone know of a way to have both filters without having to explicitly set all options and nix using .setMimeTypeFilters?

You could add custom mime types with a personalized MIME xml. See the QMimeDatabase documentation.

Combining mime-filters and name-filters is quite easy to achieve using QMimeDatabase. Doing things this way will allow you to merge glob patterns (e.g. *.qss with the css defaults), as well as getting full control over the final ordering of the filters. This won't normally be possible when using the QFileDialog methods.
Below is a simple function that demonstrates the idea. The function takes a dict with mime-type/filter-name keys and glob-list values. If the function detects a mime-type, the glob-list will be merged with the built-in defaults. The return value is a list that can be passed to setNameFilters. The code logic is essentially the same as what QFileDialog itself uses, but tweaked slightly to allow greater flexibility:
def combine_filters(filters):
    result = []
    md = QMimeDatabase()
    for name, patterns in filters.items():
        if (mt := md.mimeTypeForName(name)).isValid():
            if mt.isDefault():
                result.append('All Files (*)')
                continue
            name = mt.comment()
            patterns = sorted(mt.globPatterns() + list(patterns or ()))
        result.append(f'{name} ({" ".join(patterns)})')
    return result

Example with merge:
filters = combine_filters({
    'text/css': ['*.qss'],
    'application/octet-stream': None,
    })

print('\n'.join(filters))

# CSS stylesheet (*.css *.qss)
# All Files (*)

Example without merge:
filters = combine_filters({
    'text/css': None,
    'Qt Style Sheet': ['*.qss'],
    'application/octet-stream': None,
    })

print('\n'.join(filters))

# CSS stylesheet (*.css)
# Qt Style Sheet (*.qss)
# All Files (*)


From the documentation of setMimeTypeFilters(), which states that (1) setMimeTypeFilters() is a "convenience method for setNameFilters()" and that (2) "calling setMimeTypeFilters overrides any previously set name filters, and changes the return value of nameFilters()", we can conclude that setMimeTypeFilters() does nothing but setting name filters internally, as well.
Following this related question, we can use this knowledge to our advantage, by applying the following steps:

Set the MIME type filters with setMimeTypeFilters().
Get the resulting name filters with nameFilters().
Complete the resulting list with our name filter(s), e.g. using append().
Update/override the filters, using the completed list, with setNameFilters().

This could look as follows:
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QFileDialog

app = QApplication([])

file_dialog = QFileDialog()
file_dialog.setFileMode(QFileDialog.FileMode.ExistingFiles)
mime_filters = ["text/css", "application/octet-stream"]
file_dialog.setMimeTypeFilters(mime_filters)
name_filters = file_dialog.nameFilters()
name_filters.append("Qt Style Sheet (*.qss)")
file_dialog.setNameFilters(name_filters)

if file_dialog.exec():
    print(file_dialog.selectedFiles())

For me, this produces the following filters:

Note that application/octet-stream resolves to "All files (*)" here. This might be a bit surprising, but seems reasonable on a Linux system (where I am working on), where applications do not share a particular suffix.
